# Invalid Bundle. The bundle xxx does not support the minimum OS version (2020)

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store, app-store-connect, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac. I have set the deployment target to version 10. and receive the error while trying to sign and distribute the archive to App Store. Or I should set the deployment target higher than 10? How to set the minimum supported OS version in the bundle?

I know that this question had been asked and I have read them and tried the solutions, but those questions' answers were for older version of system. Things changed throughout the years, I find that the old answers are no more applicable.

Note: I'm using the latest version of MacOs, XCode, Xamarin and Visual Studio

[image: error screenshot]

[image: info.plist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys. I get a hint from a programmer saying that I might have included a component or feature that is not supported in the old version of iOS. I'm unable to identify which component or feature within my project. Therefore, I rebuild the whole project from scratch and carefully select the components and features and ... success. It gets uploaded successfully to appstore. And the minimum deployment target iOS is set to 10.

Until now, I still have no idea which component or feature from the previous build raised the conflict of minimum iOS version.

Nonetheless, thanks for your time guys.